# Checkbox value is always empty even if i check it

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I made a button to delete files from a database, to delete a file you need to check a checkbox and then click a button. somewhy when i click the button and write the checkbox value to the html it always says false...

ASPX:

```html
<asp:GridView HorizontalAlign="Center" ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">< ItemTemplate >
                            < asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="OpenDocument" Text='<%# Eval("File_Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">< ItemTemplate >
                            < asp:CheckBox ID = "CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Update" ID="Update" class="button" OnClick="UpdateTable" Style="font-size: 20px" />
```

Code Behind:

```cs
protected void UpdateTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (chk != null)
        {
            //This is being written and always false
            Response.Write(chk.Checked);
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
               //Delete the item. (never being executed)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected chk.Checked to be True since i've clicked it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are binding your grid in Page_Load, Make sure you are not binding your grid outside of if(!IsPostBack){}. Otherwise you'll loose the checkboxes on each postback and so losing the status of checkboxes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       //Bind Your Grid Here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what 'binding grid' means... but to make it easier Under the Page_Load i have only 1 function which is:
[Picture](http://prntscr.com/nvs72d)
also maybe me using `Text='<%# Eval("File_Name");%>` in the other column is the problem...

Comment: Ok yea it was indeed the function under pageload. thanks alot tho another problem has revealed. when i need to get the LinkButton text from the first column i use `item.Cells[0].Text` but somewhy it is null. maybe because it's a LinkButton and not text it doesn't work but i'm not quiet sure

Answer (score 1):

item.Cells[0].Text will not work as the grid column is defined as TemplateField and not as BoundField. So we need to access the control using FindControl and retrieve the text from it.

```
protected void UpdateTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
                if (chk != null)
                {
                    //This is being written and always false
                    Response.Write(chk.Checked);
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        //Delete the item. (never being executed)
                    }
                }
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("LinkButton2");
                if (lnk != null)
                {
                    Response.Write(lnk.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yea it worked for me tho i found out about it just before you posted... thanks anyways it will help other people with the same problem